# Please help to increase my root partition size

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I really need to increase my root file system size to atleast 20 gb. Right now I am running out of space. And I dont want to re install everything again. I have attached a screenshot of gparted. Any help will be appreciated. That 145 Gb partition is my C drive where windows in installed.

## I am really bad in partitioning disks. Thats why I am asking here :)

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 Gnome in an Asus UX303 LN (if it matters)[image]

Comment: I saw that thread. but the partitions are different. and as mentioned in my thread i am really bad in that. So am expecting a step by step instructions based on my partitions

Comment: That post already has step by step instructions. All you need to do is resize sda9 and add that space to sda11. We can't post the same exact information, just changing the partition names each time a new user has the same issue. That defeats the purpose of having duplicates. If this is still confusing to you, visit [chat] and we'd be happy to help out.

Comment: I am trying it out and if its not working i will use the chat. Thanks

Comment: You need to get some free space first.